# Possible to simultaneously run mongo cluster on AWS EC2 & AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

We currently have a mongodb cluster of 3 EC2 servers setup on m5.xlarge instances. All 3 are standard RIs. The issue is that when particular queries are run, the server's CPU utilization goes to 99% & eventually it either slows down or stops.

The devs have tried to optimized the queries. We also got rid of any unnecessary storage & applications on server. But the issue still occurs.

We checked out AWS documentdb & would like to try it. However, will current mongo cluster + new setup in documentdb work? Or it will be different.

So far, we have got how to migrate or to create cluster in documentdb. Has anyone tried to work these two simultaneosly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Database Migration Service (DMS) to copy the data from MongoDB to DocumentDB and keep them in sync while you're performing your tests. Or, just mongodump/mongorestore and test your application in staging environment, this is what I would initially anyway. There are some tools as well in the DocumentDB tools [repository](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-documentdb-tools), one is the [compatibility tool](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-documentdb-tools/tree/master/compat-tool) which you can use to scan your code base or MongoDB logs for any unsupported operators.